# Excel 2010 > Chart Axis Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, axis

I have a chart that has a primary and secondary headings.  But, in the chart I can't find a way to just bold the primary heading.  The table that the chart is created from has the primary headings bolded but does not carry over to the chart.  Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the primary heading text, then go to the Home Tab on the ribbon and click the **bold** button in the Font group.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  :)  What I'm trying to do is just bold the primary title in the chart and not the sub headings.

Comment: Forgot one tiny thing...I can't select just the primary heading in the chart.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the chart. Could you upload a picture of it to, say, imgur.com and then either include the link to the picture in your question or in a comment? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no way to do that. Multi-level column headings will be treated as one piece of information on a chart axis and you cannot create different formats for the different levels. Axis titles are notoriously unwieldy when it comes to formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  It's unfortunate that Excel does not have that capability.  It would be very helpful.   :)